# The order of $im(\nu'_*)\subseteq \pi_*S^3$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homotopy-groups-of-sphere

The 3-sphere $S^3$ has homotopy 2-exponent 4. That is, any 2-torsion element $\alpha\in\pi_*S^3$ has order at most 4. This bound is sharp, for example the Blakers-Massey element $\nu'\in\pi_6S^3$ has order 4 (throughout this question we shall agree to work at the prime 2).

Now glancing at the unstable homotopy of $S^3$ up to around $\pi_{30}$ it seems like every non-trivial composition of the form $\nu'\circ\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in\pi_rS^6$, $r\gt 6$ has order at most 2. Here is my question:

Is the submodule $\nu'_*(\pi_rS^6)\subseteq\pi_rS^3$, $r\gt 6$ torsion order at most 2? If not is there a counterexample? If so, is this understood? If so is it more general? Is $\nu'_*([A,S^6])\subseteq [A,S^3]$ torsion of order 2 for any (finite) 6-connected complex A?

Comment: In all questions the identity of $S^6$ has to be excluded.

Comment: We can still take $A=S^6\vee S^7$ and the collapse map in $[A,S^6]$.